# How to add Authorization header for every client request in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I am new in ASP.NET. So, somehow I create a JWT token and set [Authorize] attribute for some controllers. How can i set Authorization header with that token for every client request?

The problem is that [Authorize] called before constructor of a controller or even before my custom middleware

I tried use filters and middleware but it didn't work. Tried to set headers with HttpClient and HttpContext.

Comment: Going to need a little more context to get a concrete answer here, otherwise its just guesswork. If I had to *guess*, I would say you should create a custom Controller which had all your attributes and whatnot tied into it, then inherit from it wherever you want that behavior.